# Page lagging when query big data in database Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Suppose the query will filter the data and return the filtered data into a datatable(yagra), However, the system lags (the page keep loading) once I run as the data is too large(more than 5m data). What should I add so that it can load the large data and pass to a datatable. I'm using facade not eloquent and know its either chunk/query pagination can solve it.
The query code is as below:

```
    $data = $query->select('table1.id','table2.First_name')->get();
```

Would appreciate if someone can help with any suggestion how I can deal with this problem case? The aim is just to filter the data and export it as csv (which I successfully did it with smaller database I tested before), but the problem appeared as the current database I just connected is way too large to be run with the existing query I created.

engines in config file:

```
'engines'        => [
    'eloquent'   => Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable::class,
    'query'      => Yajra\DataTables\QueryDataTable::class,
    'collection' => Yajra\DataTables\CollectionDataTable::class,
    'resource'   => Yajra\DataTables\ApiResourceDataTable::class,
],

/*
 * DataTables accepted builder to engine mapping.
 * This is where you can override which engine a builder should use
 * Note, only change this if you know what you are doing!
 */
'builders'       => [
   // Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::class => 'eloquent',
    // Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::class            => 'eloquent',
    // Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::class               => 'query',
    // Illuminate\Support\Collection::class                   => 'collection',
],
```

version of yagra is :

```
    name : yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
    descrip. : jQuery DataTables API for Laravel 4|5
    keywords : datatables, jquery, laravel
    versions : * v9.7.2
```

Comment: use pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pagination as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination).

```
$records_per_page = 50;
$data = $query->select('table1.id','table2.First_name')->paginate($records_per_page);
```

Then in your view, you can use the pagiation links like

```
{{ $data->links() }}
```

Comment: is pagination query same as pagination datatable? because if yes, I have done the pagination datatable but it still not working

Comment: No. If you use pagination in the query, only a given number of records will be fetched from the database at a time. Right now you are getting all records at once from the db which will be very slow if the data is huge.

Comment: error No available engine for Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator

Comment: please show me the 'engines' part in the config file.  which version are you using for yajra?

Comment: update with datatable engine and yagra version in question

Comment: Thanks, it works. I removed the paginate and use the server-side script datatable plugins. the process still quite slow, but luckily it works at least :)

Comment: Why have you commented out builders in the config file?

Comment: by default its commented. Already uncommented them but still the error appears. so I removed the paginate() and use the server-side script datatable